# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\log(1+y)/y$ without LHR or Taylor series

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Problem 12 on p. 297 of Spivak's *Calculus* (first edition) is

> Find $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\log (1+y)/y$. (You can use L'Hospital's
>   rule, but that would be silly.)

I'm not sure the other method he's looking for besides LHR. I can also think of expanding $\log(1+y)$ in Taylor series, but this is before the section of the book on Taylor series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\lim_{y\to 0} {\log(1 + y)\over y}= \lim_{y\to 0} {\log(1 + y) - \log(1)\over y} = \log'(1) = 1.$$

Comment: A-ha, of course. :)

Answer (score 14):

$$
\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\log(1+y)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0} \log(1+y)^{1/y} = \log \lim_{y\to 0} (1+y)^{1/y} = \log e = 1
$$

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 - he is using the rule $a \log(b)$ = $\log(b^a)$ with $a = 1/y$ and $b = 1 + y$.

Comment: @breeden ty  ....

Comment: Nice alternate method!